# TikZ connecting shapes together

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I am a newbie in TeX programming. I want to draw objects like on the attached figure.

[image]

It does not have to the exact same shapes.

The only thing that I've learned so far is drawing shapes.

```
\draw[blue] (0,0)rectangle (3,2);
\draw[blue] (5,0)rectangle (8,2);
```

The question is how I can connect different shapes together. The connections and the arrows are mandatory.

Comment: This could help you http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/flowcharts/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) node 
  [fill=blue!20, shape=rectangle, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm]
 (A){dataset};
\draw (5,0) node 
  [fill=yellow!20, shape=rectangle, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm]
 (B){};
\draw (7,3) node 
  [fill=red!20, shape=circle,  minimum width=30]
 (C){};

\draw[line width=2pt]  (A) -- (B);
\draw [line width=2pt,->] (B) -- (C);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to modify code later if relative rather than absolute positioning is used. `on grid` placement helps to keep things tidy. `shapes.geometric` supplies a `diamond` shape and styles are used to keep formatting consistent. `arrows.meta` supplies enhanced arrow tips and the `graphs` library makes it a little easier to draw the connections. `shadows.blur` is for egregious bling.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz,dvipsnames,svgnames,rgb]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,positioning,graphs,shadows.blur}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    >=Latex,
    thick,
    base/.style={draw=#1!50, fill=#1!20, font=\sffamily, text opacity=1, on grid, node distance=20mm, blur shadow},
    my diamond/.style={base=green, aspect=7.5, diamond, minimum height=10mm},
    block/.style={base=blue, minimum width=20mm, minimum height=10mm},
    my circle/.style={base=red, circle, minimum size=10mm},
  ]
  \node (ds) [block] {DATASET};
  \node (c1) [my circle, above right=of ds] {};
  \node (dia) [my diamond, above right=of c1] {};
  \node (c2) [my circle, below right=of dia] {};
  \node (blk) [block, below right=of c2] {};
  \graph [use existing nodes] {
    ds -- c1 -> dia -- c2 -> blk
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Ti*k*Z features for flowcharts with bling]